# Entity Framework works until I deploy to the new production server. Schema specified is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I've been using Entity Framework 6 in my WCF service for quite a while now.  This past week the need arose to move the service from its current Windows Server 2008 box to a Windows server 2012 box.  The code has worked fine until it was deployed to the new server, now I'm getting the following error message when I try to access:

> "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\nVDFCOREModel.msl(3,4) :
>   error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and
>   AssociationSet in the EntityContainer ."

This is a database first implementation and nothing has changed with
the Entity Model from one server to another.

I have to assume there is something about the server that is not configured properly, but can't figure out what that may be.

The service is being built to target .Net 4.5.
Here is the stack trace in case that could help anyone: at

> System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.Init(EdmItemCollection
>   edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1
>   xmlReaders, IList`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection..ctor(EdmItemCollection
>   edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1
>   xmlReaders, IList`1 filePaths)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection
>   edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__1()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__4()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadAndCheckItemCollection[T](Func`1
>   itemCollectionLoader)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.<>c__DisplayClass16.<.ctor>b__f()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()--- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace
>   dataSpace, Boolean required)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace
>   dataSpace)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InitializeMappingViewCacheFactory(DbContext
>   owner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection
>   connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor,
>   ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory,
>   Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path)
>   at .LoadUser(String userName, LoadUserContainer&
>   userContainer) in .cs:line 157

Comment: It seems that your model is not right. Is the database still the same? Try to  `Update Model from Database`

Comment: I've tried updating and validating the model then re-deploying and still get the same message.  Again, this same deployment works on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Comment: Is the database local to the server or are both servers trying to access the same remote database ?

Comment: Both web servers are accessing a separate remote database.  I have also verified connection to the remote database on the new web server.

Comment: I am assuming SQLServer here. What version of SqlServer is on your remote databases ? What version of the Sql Native Client is on your Windows server ?

Comment: Yes, this is SQL Server 2008 SP3.  Both the old and new servers have both SQL Native Client 10.0 (2009.100.1600.01) and 11.0 (2011.110.2100.60) installed.